# StackOverFlowError when I use addPoint() method on LineGraphView object in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, stack-overflow, linegraph

```
// Initializing the LineGraphView object and adding it to linLayout 
        graph = new LineGraphView(rootView.getContext(), 100, Arrays.asList("x", "y", "z"));
        linLayout.addView(graph);
        graph.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {
            // Obtaining accelerometer values
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];

            float pythagorean = (float)Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);

            List<Float> graph_points = new ArrayList<Float>();
            graph_points.add(pythagorean);

            output.setText("\npythagorean\n"
                    + "pythagorean: " + String.valueOf(pythagorean));

            // Adding the current accelerometer values to the LinearGraphView object
            graph.addPoint(graph_points); 

        }
    }
```

`graph.addPoint(graph_points);` //I get a stackOverFlow Error, it keeps adding a point to the graph and the Android app crashes.

`graph.addPoint(event.values);`//This gives no stackoverflow error, it nicely graphs, x, y, z on the graph.

What I don't understand is, the `event.values` object is the same type as the `graph_points` object that I created. They are both `List<Float>` java objects. Why does `event.values` work and `graph_points` crash the app?

```
// LineGraphView.java --> From LineGraphView Lib, I didn't write this!
/**
 * Adds a set of datapoints for the next x value. The data points should be in the same 
 * order as the array of labels this object was initialized with.
 * @param y The List of datapoints.
 */

public void addPoint(float[] y)
{
    points.add(y.clone());
    if(points.size() > maxDataWidth)
        points.remove(0);

    invalidate();
}

public void addPoint(List<Float> y)
{
    float[] floats = new float[y.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++){
        floats[i] = y.get(i);
    }
    addPoint(y);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using recursion without a base case? More importantly, why are you using recursion at all?

Comment: I didn't use recursion, what part of the code are you talking about?

Comment: Recursion is when a method calls itself. The last line of `addPoint()` is a call to `addPoint()`. This is what causes the `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `StackOverFlowError` occurs when you have called too many methods without returning. In this case, `addPoint()` calls itself infinitely. When a method calls itself, it is called recursion. I don't know what `addPoint()` is supposed to do, but I highly doubt that it is supposed to be recursive at all. If the recursion is intentional, the problem is that you have not created a base case which determines when the recursion stops.

Comment: I didn't write the addPoint() method, it is part of the `LineGraphView` library from Android. It works without a stackOverFlowError when the parameter is `event.values` instead of a `List<Float>` object that I created.

Comment: @tnecniv `LineGraphView` is not a standard Android class. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I think it's from here: [link](https://github.com/ChromoZoneX/pedometer/blob/master/Pedometer5/src/com/hades/pedometer5/LineGraphView.java)

Comment: should I stop using the ListGraphView object altogether? Is there a standard Android Lib I can use to display a graph for accelerator data?

Comment: @tnecniv I don't know of any such standard library. Did you download the source code for this `LineGraphView` or did you add a dependency in `build.gradle`? When using third-party libraries, gradle is the preferred method of setting up dependencies.

Comment: @tnecniv It appears that the version of `LineGraphView` which you are using is broken. Not only does the `addPoint()` method call itself, it also doesn't appear to do anything useful from the code you posted here. I suggest you obtain the most recent version of this library to use. This is easy to do if you learn a little about configuring `build.gradle`.

Comment: Well it's another file inside Android Studio, it's right next to MainActivity.java.

Comment: @tnecniv Android Studio had to get it from somewhere. What directory is the `LineGraphView.java` file saved in?

Comment: I just realized, there are two addPoint() functions. It is not doing recursion. I have updated my description. Now the question is, where is the stack over flow coming from?

Comment: if there are two addPoint() functions, the second should take a different paramater than List<Float> y. When you use the same argument you call the same functions so your addPoint function calls itself infinitely. You might try renaming your function to addPoints(List<Float> y) then verify you are passing the correct argument to the addPoint() function.

Comment: See, your edit makes it clear, in the first addPoint() function you need to finish with addPoint(floats) not addPoint(y);

Comment: @tnecniv As it stands, the `addPoint(List<Float>)` function **is** recursive because it calls itself. I think you mean to make it call `addPoint(float[])` instead. Part of the confusion is that these two methods have the same name, but they are two very distinct methods because of the different parameter lists.

Comment: @tnecniv This appears to be a bug in the `LineGraphView` class from the library you are using. You should consider reporting it to the original author.